# How to divide a generic resource?

Tags: ms-project, resource-planning

I am still new at using ms project Professional. My project has already assigned resources.

For instance, let's take developers who together have a maximum effort of 200%, which means I have 2 developers.

My question is: how do I divide that generic resource into 2 individuals?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Do you currently have a generic resource that is over allocated on the project?  If so, create multiple resources and set them to % each, so developer 1 and developer 2 both at 50% each on a task.

Comment: First read “Mythical man month” by Fred Brooks.

Comment: Is this a software or other design project? Or something else?

Answer (score 1):

There isn’t an automatic way to replace a single assigned generic with two non-generic resources. You will need to replace the generic with the first developer and then just assign the 2nd one manually.

Bake sure that the resource driven setting on the task is set so that the 2nd resource being added results in the correct distribution of the total task work.